# C++ Boost:: How to create a map from vertex descriptor?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I tried to define map, but it doesn't let me to define:

```
....
typename graph_traits<MyGraphType>::vertex_descriptor NodeID;
typedef map<size_t, NodeID> IndexMap; //doesn't let me to create this
...
MyGraphType(10);
...
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `typename` doesn't look as if it belongs in your snippet. (Which is too short to say anything.) Try:

```
typedef graph_traits<MyGraphType>::vertex_descriptor NodeID;
```